# How to replace a value in immutable arrays scala

Tags: arrays, scala, replace, immutability

I have an array

```
val doot = Array("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to replace the 2nd index with the letter "z", but I do not want to modify doot. I want to create a new array, as that seems to be the idiom in scala.

So far, I can only modify the array with update

```
doot.update(1, "z") // But now doot is modified directly, not ideal!
```

Does scala offer a way to do this?

Comment: To be clear on language: you can't "replace" a value in an `immutable array` since it's immutable. i.e. cannot change.

Comment: To be further clear on language: There is no such thing as an "immutable array" in scala. There is only one `Array`, and it is mutable.

Comment: Well, that's good to know! My wording was off yeah, the point was that I cannot replace a value in an immutable array.. I wanted to create a new array with that value replaced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scala> val doot = Array("a", "b", "c")
doot: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> val eoot = doot.updated(1, "z")
eoot: Array[String] = Array(a, z, c)

scala> doot
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> eoot
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, z, c)
```